# imacros javascript conditional eval statement

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, conditional-statements, imacros

Trying to insert a conditional "if Else" statement using the imacros EVAL using the same format from a few examples I came across. However it seems I'm still missing a thing or two.

```
 TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:log-1 EXTRACT=TXT
 SET !VAR7 {{!EXTRACT}}
 TAG POS=2 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:log-1 EXTRACT=TXT
 SET !VAR6 {{!EXTRACT}} 
 SET !NEWVAR EVAL("var s=\"{{!VAR6}}}\"; if(s==\"#EANF#\") {s=\"!VAR6\";} else {s=\"!VAR7\";}")
 PROMPT !NEWVAR
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
' ...
SET NEWVAR EVAL("('{{!VAR6}}' == '#EANF#') ? '{{!VAR6}}' : '{{!VAR7}}';")
PROMPT {{NEWVAR}}
```

Comment: What a neat operator. Thanks